# ListView Android with Button in ListItem

Tags: android, listview, button, action

I have class ListItem that represent an item from ListView:

```
public class ListItem extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Uri[] image;
private String[] text;
private Activity context;
private Button button;
public ListItem(Activity context, String[] text, Uri[] image) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, text);
    
    this.context = context;
    this.image = image;
    this.text = text;
    
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
    button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_button_buy);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);
    
    textView.setText(text[position]);
    imageView.setImageURI(image[position]);
    
    return rowView;
}
}
```

on ListView I set list Adapter:

```
list.setAdapter(new ListItem(context,items,images));
```

I need to set action for Button from ListItem, action I need to set in ListView because I need to know number of list item where Button is clicked.

When user click this button I want to add an Product item to ArrayList, for this I need to know number of button clicked ( count starts from top - 0 ).

LE: When I click on ListItem I don't see visual effect, I need to activate it.

Please help me.
[image]

Comment: This is a very common question.  To the right are **Related** questions.  Start with those.  You can also google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right. Is the problem only the Button click? That's easy to do. Create a ClickListener class that stores the item position.

```
public class MyClickListener implements ClickListener {
    private int position;

    public MyClickListener(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) { ... }
}
```

and set it on your `getView()` method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    ...
    rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_button).setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(position));
    ...
}
```

Here you go, you know the item position in the listener.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was that I tried to set OnClickListener in constructor, now in getView() method is working fine. Thanks.